# Incoming transaction confirmed but not showing in Mist wallet

Tags: transactions, wallets, ether

I trasnferred E10 from Kraken on 05-04-16 13:20:09 +0100 to address `0x023d29a271b2a2406ceedf208f7e36e9e24ff23d` with the transaction ID `0x22af76e14762e756e842bb30658a66a6fa45c763d8f5de2e8f9512921ce812dc`.

The transaction has been validated over 100 times but my wallet shows no balance.

Wallet is new and blockchain is still syncing.

Any ideas on why this happens or I should go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Mist only grabs incoming transactions for wallet contracts, not normal accounts.

Mist will also show any outgoing transactions done via the Mist interface.

So...

- If I send 1ETH from Account 1 to Account 2 *and* Account 1 is in Mist *and* I send the transaction via Mist, it will show up.
- If I send 1ETH from Kraken to Mist Account, it won't show up.
- If I send 1ETH from Kraken to Mist Wallet Contract, it will show up.
- If I send 1ETH from Mist Account or Wallet Contract to Kraken, it will show up.
- If I send 1ETH via MyEtherWallet but the account is also imported into Mist, it will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You will see it when blockchain is in full sync. However you can verify this on other public places.

If you want to see it your own copy, please wait till until it fully syncs.

Comment: Welcome!  Someone has downvoted your answer maybe because you didn't explain more "why this happens".  It is probably also helpful to link to the community wiki about block explorers, instead of just mentioning "public places".