# Transaction mined or not?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, synchronization, confirmations, txpool

Several hours ago I sent the transaction 0xe9cca30f9d8d2040a3c6c5ceb6601240b0c095a47ac9117dd34e36c0d66be2f7 into Ethereum testnet. When asking a node about it, everything seems right (confirmed transaction):

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xe9cca30f9d8d2040a3c6c5ceb6601240b0c095a47ac9117dd34e36c0d66be2f7");
{
  blockHash: "0xed3c145b87b83a52c42eb9f54c02e05be0da4b0723faf82ee1237b1b599bd180",
  blockNumber: 1806280,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 43282,
  from: "0xbeb1c53c48f916e099f0d13d3c65f8943dd8ddd2",
  gasUsed: 22282,
  logs: [],
  root: "53f83e77cd68ccee638efcb753426238d5483bf9879086fd3e19288742515596",
  to: "0x27c042342c9ba937214117e11a4970a6145034cb",
  transactionHash: "0xe9cca30f9d8d2040a3c6c5ceb6601240b0c095a47ac9117dd34e36c0d66be2f7",
  transactionIndex: 1
}
```

Nevertheless, this transaction is not visible through etherscan explorer:

https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xe9cca30f9d8d2040a3c6c5ceb6601240b0c095a47ac9117dd34e36c0d66be2f7

> Unable to locate Transaction entry

Not sure if it has something to do with [Incoming transaction confirmed but not showing in Mist wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/incoming-transaction-confirmed-but-not-showing-in-mist-wallet)

Is there any reason that can explain the anomaly? Thx!

Comment: You're clearly not on the morden testnet, since it is only up to block 1802845. Could you give us some more details about your setup?

Comment: Your block number is close but not at the public Testnet as @TjadenHess mentioned above.

One possibility is that you are not running the gas price hard fork client and you are syncing to the non-hard forked Testnet chain. From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/c72f5459ac110de47fa068bfa560164078508b1e, the Testnet gas price fork block is 1783000. You should be running geth v1.4.18 or later - https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.4.18 .

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation for the anomaly, you could be locally mining the transaction but not connected to other morden testnet peers.

The following may help if this is the case:

See: [Geth - Checking Connectivity](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#checking-connectivity)

Specifically, the following commands.

```
> net.listening
> net.peerCount
> admin.peers
```

You could also check your balance (locally) and confirm that it matches the expected results in the blockchain explorer.

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance('0xbeb1c53c48f916e099f0d13d3c65f8943dd8ddd2'), 'ether')
```

Should match the balance [here](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xbeb1c53c48f916e099f0d13d3c65f8943dd8ddd2).

Comment: This may be correct, but it would be unusual for a the local blockchain to be ahead of the true chain, since the first few blocks would take an extremely long time to mine. It could happen, with all the DoS attacks lately

Comment: @TjadenHess true / good point.

To the original poster: [BokkyPooBah's post above](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9581/transaction-mined-or-not#comment9874_9581) is also very much on point / a good possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the problem might be running an old version of geth, not suitable for EIP150 Hardfork. After upgrading geth from v1.4.10 to v1.4.18 everything should run smoothly again. Thx!