# Transaction not performed, morden.ether.camp has different transactions than me (Morden)

Tags: transactions, blocks, balances, morden, ether-camp

I'm on morden network. I received Ether and waited roughly one hour, but I have

```
> web3.eth.getBalance("0x3061c735f4e9172a3c66d07fcde6ea560bb3369c")
0
```

However, the transaction is confirmed: https://morden.ether.camp/account/3061c735f4e9172a3c66d07fcde6ea560bb3369c

The block height of the transaction is 1809897
My current, local block height is 1815160

I'm sure that I'm on morden network:

```
> web3.version.network
"2"
```

I can also get the block of the transaction locally:

```
> web3.eth.getBlock(1809897)
{
  difficulty: 72776409,
  extraData: "0xd783010500844765746887676f312e362e32856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 279285,
  hash: "0x1d61d5f870cf6ff34d21f1b149837f8976afecb42a2c0bb16aaadd2b3fcbbcf9",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000020000000000000000000000400000020000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000100000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000001000000000080000000",
  miner: "0x1a95ad5ccdb0677af951810c6ddf4935afe4e5a6",
  nonce: "0x41188b0036d6f428",
  number: 1809897,
  parentHash: "0xe7b103831a249d342af91afd38681a6879a116c73976e719af505e936d5447b0",
  receiptRoot: "0x8454af377c2d0c2fc1b3aabb8aab2ef091b261b909f452877592da7d4214ee7a",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 1540,
  stateRoot: "0x1f22dd621f29a7048c91d8bf27ad58097879d6113ea55ebbfdf76c4b9fa12d5b",
  timestamp: 1477440163,
  totalDifficulty: 396370280401374,
  transactions: ["0x9e22a769d471741076615f75203c497b23c73858e2b8c646e288a197ac9401ad", "0xedcdca0a79d81b991e1d1039b7d9fc9efd6641662277ac0a090964b3647bade3", "0x15ac720b35a041fd47e886247456fdd91bec27dea5a58a19680da71154aedfd6", "0x5b90ae3d3b1ccb0fe1b97f8996c0410e914f6c38a8e04e9c7837210918e9fd6b", "0x50cee136c698f55595b6045cc0b26dd056923b0810a044d6b94688842acef05c", "0x8a25ebd39eba4bd2b4617b7792cbe244d7b08c620c8c98c32b6f262abe77a48a"],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56947cbb413c380e9c474602fc8af0230276d5ea6449658c5b2fa7cb4658dc23",
  uncles: []
}
```

If I look at https://morden.ether.camp/block/1809897, it has 137 transactions. My local block only has 6. Block hash is different.

How's that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are running `geth` version [1.4.18](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.4.18) or later (I don't know about the 1.5x dev version). For Parity, Ethereum Wallet and EthereumJ, see [FAQ: Upcoming Ethereum Hard Fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/).

This hard fork took place on Aug 18 2016, but some miners on the Morden network are running the older version of the clients that don't support the hard fork. And other miners on the Morden network are running the new clients that support the hard fork. There are two Morden chains running in parallel.

Following is the message on my `geth --testnet console` running the hard forked `geth` v1.4.18:

```
I1028 23:53:39.912288 miner/worker.go:435] � �  Mined 5 blocks back: block #1811576
I1028 23:53:42.790480 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 4 txs in 13.470183ms. #1811582 [6f744396 / 6f744396]
I1028 23:53:42.791202 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 1811583 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 505.014µs
E1028 23:54:05.999001 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1783000 (0x37d8ca5f8cbbb989c8b6da426a16b51d508fbf1402c44cdc0f2ac82bfd422be5)
E1028 23:54:05.999035 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (108116 / 109916)
E1028 23:54:51.148578 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1783000 (0x37d8ca5f8cbbb989c8b6da426a16b51d508fbf1402c44cdc0f2ac82bfd422be5)
E1028 23:54:51.148609 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (108116 / 109916)
I1028 23:55:06.231641 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 8.589212ms. #1811583 [67df5be8 / 67df5be8]
I1028 23:55:06.233454 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 1811584 with 2 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.583941ms
E1028 23:55:54.481206 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1783000 (0x37d8ca5f8cbbb989c8b6da426a16b51d508fbf1402c44cdc0f2ac82bfd422be5)
E1028 23:55:54.481240 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (108116 / 109916)
I1028 23:56:06.003655 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 2 txs in 7.919943ms. #1811584 [12f573af / 12f573af]
```

In line #2 above, you can see a block received from another node client on the hard forked chain.

In line #4 above, you can see a block received from another node client on the non-hard forked chain. As the gas values for some underpriced opcodes were repriced, the gas calculations are different and so this block is rejected by my node client.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are running a client which does not enforce the EIP150 Hardfork.  For example, if you are running geth 1.4.17 (or prior), you may receive results like this.

There are other possibilities, but this seems to be the most common explanation currently.

See:

[Similar Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9581/transaction-mined-or-not)